# What's the preferred way to dump a JSON object? to_json, JSON.generate or JSON.dump?

Tags: ruby, json

I need to dump a hash object to JSON and I was wondering which of these three, `to_json`, `JSON.generate` or `JSON.dump`, is the preferred way to do it.

I've tested the results of these methods and they are the same:

```
> {a: 1, b: 2}.to_json
=> "{\"a\":1,\"b\":2}" 
> JSON.generate({a: 1, b: 2})
=> "{\"a\":1,\"b\":2}" 
> JSON.dump({a: 1, b: 2})
=> "{\"a\":1,\"b\":2}"
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html):

> `JSON.generate` only allows objects or arrays to be converted to JSON syntax. `to_json`, however, accepts many Ruby classes even though it acts only as a method for serialization

and

> [`JSON.dumps`] is part of the implementation of the load/dump interface of Marshal and YAML.
>
> If `anIO` (an `IO`-like object or an object that responds to the write method) was given, the resulting JSON is written to it.

Comment: I still don't find any major difference between `generate` and `dumps` besides the optional file argument and the limit. Is that it?

Comment: Pretty much. As the docs say, `#dump` is there to allow you to do something like `serializer = [JSON, Marshal, YAML][rand(3)]; serializer.dump(obj, io, limit)`. (well, a more useful thing would be to select the serialiser in a config file, for example, but it takes more space than random selection :P ).

Answer (score 4):

`JSON.generate` only allows objects or arrays to be converted to JSON syntax.

`to_json` accepts many Ruby classes even though it acts only as a method for serialization

```
JSON.generate(1)
JSON::GeneratorError: only generation of JSON objects or arrays allowed

1.to_json
=> "1"
```

`JSON.dump`: Dumps obj as a JSON string, calls generate on the object and returns the result.

You can get more info from [here](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html)

Answer (score 3):

For dumping arrays, hashs and objects (converted by `to_hash`), these 3 ways are equivalent.

But `JSON.generate` or `JSON.dump` only allowed arrays, hashs and objects.

`to_json` accepts many Ruby classes even though it acts only as a method for serialization, like a integer:

```
JSON.generate 1 # would be allowed
1.to_json # => "1"
```

`JSON.generate` took more options for output style (like space, indent)

And `JSON.dump`, output default style, but took a IO-like object as second argument to write, third argument as limit number of nested arrays or objects.

Answer (score 2):

Working with a huge hash (300MB), `to_json` was unable to generate the json string, it crashed.
However `JSON.generate` did work, and so did `JSON.dump`.